# PhpStorm switches Git branches randomly

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I checkout to any branch in terminal (current develop, new - feature), PhpStorm selects in its Git tab (pic 1) random origin branch (origin/bug/ert...) instead of leaving all as should be on pic 2.

Pic 1:

[image]

Pic 2:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you should open an issue on their bugtracker for this

Comment: already, but someone might had that resolved...

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54353

Comment: in feedback from jetbrains I saw "We also recommend checking http://stackoverflow.com/ for similar questions."

Comment: Well, did you…? 

Comment: sure I did :)))

Answer (score 1):

Please see and vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238314

The filter can be updated if there is any branch selected in Branches pane of a left side of IDE.